# Scala prepending to ListBuffer puzzler

Tags: scala

Using Scala 2.10.3. The following code works for me:

```
val sequence = new ListBuffer[Int]()
sequence.+=:(x)
```

but if I write:

```
val sequence = new ListBuffer[Int]()
sequence +=: x
```

I get:

```
value +=: is not a member of Int
  sequence +=: x
       ^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any operator ending in `:` is right-associative.

So when you write:

```
sequence +=: x
```

It gets parsed as:

```
x.+=:(sequence)
```

Which of course fails, because `x` doesn't have a `+=:` method

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, methods ending in a colon are invoked on the right argument instead of the left, so your second example is

```
x.+=:(sequence)
```

which fails since `Int` has no such operator.

Answer (score 1):

`+=:` is a prepend operator (like `::` for immutable Lists) so it makes sense to be right associative

```
1 +=: 2 +=: 3 +=: ListBuffer() += 4 += 5 += 6
  //  ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: `::` only applies to `List`, for collections in general you want `+:` and `:+`. Mix them up for extra fun: `1 +: 2 +: Seq(3,4) :+ 5 :+ 6`